# java.io.FileNotFoundException: Can't find file: How i can save xlxb file from calling URL

Tags: python, java

Their is new error now i want to download this from calling to url. Means in this code i have to upload it on live but their is no option in live that give the static path of our computer. So, now how i can save the file calling for the url.

````
import  asposecells
import urllib.request
jpype.startJVM("-Xmx10g")
from asposecells.api import Workbook
workbook = Workbook("http://localhost/cafe_ci/assets/TestFile.xlsx")
workbook.save("http://localhost/cafe_ci/assets/TestFile2.xlsb")
jpype.shutdownJVM()```

ERROR


Exception Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_jpype.cp39-win_amd64.pyd in com.aspose.cells.Workbook.<init>()

Exception: Java Exception The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
java.io.FileNotFoundException Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_7624\3627910572.py in <module>
      4 jpype.startJVM("-Xmx10g")
      5 from asposecells.api import Workbook
----> 6 workbook = Workbook("http://localhost/cafe_ci/assets/TestFile.xlsx")
      7 workbook.save("http://localhost/cafe_ci/assets/TestFile2.xlsb")
      8 jpype.shutdownJVM()

java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Can't find file: http://localhost/cafe_ci/assets/TestFile.xlsx.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t76pv.png
````

Comment: Have you tried increasing or decreasing the amount of available memory you're setting with `"-Xmx2g"`? That sets the max allocation pool to 2GB.

Comment: Yes I tried but not worked. Can u please write a code and paste it hear it really helpful to me.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: No matter the size you give it, it always gives you this error? What is the size of your Excel workbook? The name `LargeFile.xlsx` is ominous - why are you trying to pull everything through these specific libraries and frameworks, just to save the Excel workbook out again?

Comment: 320MB+ Size it's I also try in configure java and increase the size also but still same error are found

Comment: Only i just need we have to save the file in xlsb because it open in few seconds in xlsb file size will be reduce an open soons

Comment: "I also try in configure java and increase the size" -  How?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @StephenC  - I download the JVM and in configure Java App i increased the size.                      Help of this Video:- https://youtu.be/WYtH5yJRz5s

Comment: Well that is telling me that you (probably) are increasing the heap size, and that 2GB is still too small.  And that implies either it needs to be bigger still ... or the workbook you are trying to load is simply too large to handle in Java.   Java (POI) is very memory inefficient.

Comment: Okay so now how i can solve this error any solution do you have? Because i tried since last week but not worked.  And i am using anaconda 3 Jupyter Notebook.  If you have a solution please send he the correct code it's really helpful to me. Thanks @StephenC

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? Testing JPype or manipulate Excel files in Python ?

Comment: @fbattello  Hi, I just want to this code is Book2.xlsx is download in TestFile1.xlsb only need to reduce the file size that sit not testing the Jpype or manipulating the excel files

Comment: If the goal is just to convert the format.
Your solution looks quite complicated.
Why you don't do use the Aspose.Cells Java library directly in Java ?
Or better is there any executable on windows that would do the job ? the `soffice` binary from LibreOffice ?

Comment: Actually, since you are using Windows, you ought to be able to use (real) Excel to do this format conversion.   Alternatively, just get a machine with more RAM so that you can make the Java heap *as large as it needs to be* to perform the conversion.

Comment: Hii All, Please open this https://products.aspose.com/cells/python-java/conversion/xlsx-to-xlsb/    site i am solving this error because this is my project where i have to solve. Thanks.   
@StephenC   & fbattello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this to increase your memory to 2gb

`jpype.startJVM("-Xms2g")`